# Replaced Transmission

Tags: starting, nissan, maxima

I have a 1998 Nissan Maxima that needed a transmission.

I replaced the transmission and installed the battery. When I try to start the car, it will crank but will not start, what can cause this problem?

I checked all wires and connectors to make sure everything was plugged back in place and I also checked the ground, everything is good.

Only thing is car will not start, but it will crank as if something is stopping it like the security system, if you can help or have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Usually, transmissions don't have much to do with whether the engine will start or not. Does it sound like it's trying to start at all (kicks a little)? Can you hear the fuel pump kick on when you first turn the key on (before cranking it)? If not, check the fuel pump fuse to see if it's blown.